# Pair of square matrices related by traces formulas

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, moments

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that for every $k\geq 1$ it holds  $tr(A^k) = tr(B^{2k-1})$. What can we say about the possible eigenvalues of $A$ and of $B$? How limited is the set of possible eigenvalues? Must it be, for example, finite?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking...for example one could take $A=0$ and $B$ to have eigenvalues occurring in $\pm$ pairs, i.e. $(\lambda_1, -\lambda_1, \lambda_2, -\lambda_2, \dots)$ for any values of $\lambda_j$.

Comment: Since finite sets are determined by their moments, the eigenvalues of $A$ are determined by those of $B$.  The question comes down to: which sequences of odd moments are moment sequences?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that all of the nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ are the same, so $\text{tr}(A^k) = m \lambda^k$ for some $\lambda$ and some $m \le n$. If $\lambda = \frac{1}{m^2}$ then $\text{tr}(A^k) = \frac{1}{m^{2k-1}}$ and so $B$ can have eigenvalue $\frac{1}{m}$ and $\pm$ pairs as in Mike Jury's comment.

Similarly, suppose that all of the eigenvalues of $B$ that don't come in $\pm$ pairs are the same, so $\text{tr}(B^{2k-1}) = m \lambda^{2k-1}$ for some $\lambda$ and some $m \le n$. If $\lambda = m$ then $\text{tr}(B^{2k-1}) = m^{2k}$ and so $A$ can have eigenvalue $m^2$and all other eigenvalues $0$ as in Mike Jury's comment.

On the other hand, if you require that all of the nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ have distinct absolute values then I think you can show that $A$ has no nonzero eigenvalues by a comparison of the growth rates of the LHS and the RHS as $k \to \infty$.